# Namespace argument in lxml parsing

Tags: python, lxml

I have an html page that I am trying to parse. Here is what I'm doing with lxml:

```
node=etree.fromstring(html)
>>> node
<Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}html at 0x110676a70>
>>> node.xpath('//body')
[]
>>> node.xpath('body')
[]
```

Unfortunately, all my xpath calls are now returning an empty list. Why is this occurring and how would I fix this call?

Comment: it could be that all the tags are namespaced as you have guessed, might be easiest to use the html parsing module http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#parsing-html

Comment: otherwise with the namespacing you'd have to do something like: `node.xpath('//html:body', namespaces={'html':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the namespace prefix while querying. like

```
node.xpath('//html:body', namespaces={'html': 'http://...'})
```

or you can use the `.nsmap`

```
node.xpath('//html:body', namespaces=node.nsmap)
```

This assumes all the namespaces are defined on tag pointed by `node`. This is usually true for most `xml` documents.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a namespace here, as follows:

```
>>> node.xpath('//xmlns:tr', namespaces={'xmlns':'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'})
[<Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}tr at 0x11067b6c8>, <Element {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}tr at 0x11067b710>]
```

And a better way to do it would be with using `lxml's` html parser:

```
>>> node=lxml.html.fromstring(html)
>>> node.findall('body')
[<Element body at 0x1106b8f18>]
```

Comment: lxml.html.fromstring